# Address offset in RISC-V load instructions hardcoded or not?

Tags: assembly, riscv

For educational purposes I used https://godbolt.org/z/7F-Lhm to translate

```
// C++ code
char i = 3;
char A[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};  
int myfunction() {
    return A[i];
}
```

into

```
# RISC-V instructions 
myfunction():                        # @myfunction()
        lui     a0, %hi(i)
        lbu     a0, %lo(i)(a0)
        lui     a1, %hi(A)
        addi    a1, a1, %lo(A)
        add     a0, a0, a1
        lbu     a0, 0(a0)
        ret
i:
        .byte   3                       # 0x3

A:
        .ascii  "\000\001\002\003\004\005"
```

But why is `A[i]` loaded with `add a0, a0, a1`, `lbu a0, 0(a0)` and not just with `lbu a0, a0(a1)`?

It would make sense if for `lbu dest, offset(baseAdress)` only `dest` and `baseAdresse` are allowed to be register adresses, whereas `offset` is a hardcoded number in the instruction word itself. But in the same code above I see `lbu a0, %lo(i)(a0)` so `offset` can apparently also be "somewhat variable"?

Maybe the reason I don't understand this is because I don't really understand why this `$hi $lo` thing is necessary in the first place. Why are we doing `lui a0, %hi(i)`, `lbu a0, %lo(i)(a0)` instead of just `lbu a0, 0(i)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Erik Eidt said, `i` is global variable, i.e. resides somewhere in the 32/64-bit addressable memory and can change at any time.

The 32/64-bit address of `i` is loaded in two parts, since 32/64-bits can not be encoded in an immediate. `%hi(i)` and `%lo(i)` are the higher and lower part of the **address** of `i`. `i` is loaded from memory since it might have changed between calls to myfunction().

Comment: Thanks, what I missed was that `%hi(i)` and `%lo(i)` are in fact hardcoded constants as well!

Answer (score 6):

> and not just with lbu a0, a0(a1)?

RISC V (and MIPS) do not have a base register + index register addressing mode — they both have only one and that is base register + immediate.

So the register + register operation required for A+i has to be done with a separate add instruction.

> instead of just lbu a0, 0(i)?

There is not enough room in the 32-bit instruction to hold the address of a global, so multiple instructions are used.

---

You have declared the variables as globals, therefore some of this code is about accessing the globals.

```
myfunction():                        # @myfunction()
        lui     a0, %hi(i)      <--- 1st part of 2 instructions for the char i global
        lbu     a0, %lo(i)(a0)  <--- 2nd instruction for fetching the char i global
        lui     a1, %hi(A)      <--- 1st part of 2 instructions for A global array
        addi    a1, a1, %lo(A)  <--- 2nd instruction for fetching addr of A global

        add     a0, a0, a1      <--- the array indexing A + i
        lbu     a0, 0(a0)       <--- the dereference *(A+i)
        ret
i:
        .byte   3                       # 0x3

A:
        .ascii  "\000\001\002\003\004\005"
```

If you try a different approach you'll see some of this disappear so you can see the array reference more directly:

```
int myfunction(char A [], int i) {
    return A[i];
}
```

---

```
myfunction(char*, int):                      # @myfunction(char*, int)
    add     a0, a0, a1
    lbu     a0, 0(a0)
    ret
```